# CSS3 Media Queries for targeting landscape on both iPhone 4 and iPhone 5 sized screens

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am having an issue with CSS3 media queries developing a mobile site. The code below works great on iPhone 5 landscape, but not so good on iPhone 4 and below in landscape mode.

```
/* Normal css represents portrait */
.test {width:100%;}

/* Flip to landscape (working great on iPhone 5) - not so great on 4s and below */
@media screen and (orientation: landscape) {
    .test {width: 50%}
}
```

Now I need to keep the above but also target ONLY iPhone 4s and below in LANDSCAPE mode, as well as all other devices around that screen size.

Can I add another media query to target the smaller screens but also keep the styles above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, you can target landscape on both using:

```
// Iphone 5
@media screen and (orientation:landscape) {
    .test { width: 50% }
}

// Iphone 4 and below, from @Danield's example
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) 
and (orientation : landscape) { 
    .test { width: 30% }
}
```

Where the first is for iPhone 5, and the second is for iPhone 4 and below. Although, I think the second one should work for both in itself. But I can't confirm it since I don't own a 5.

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#orientation

Comment: I need two different media queries, one for landscape on iphone 5 then another one for 4s and below?

Comment: Oh god, I was a bit quick there. I'll check what seems to be wrong with `orientation: landscape` and update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Sorry i dont think i have explained myself correctly. On iphone 4 and below in landscape mode i need a media query to give .test a width:30%. Then on a iPhone 5 in landscape i need to give .test width:50%

Comment: Oh. Yes of course you can do that. My updated answer should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this site](http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/#iPhone):

iPhone 2G-4S in landscape

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) 
and (orientation : landscape) { /* STYLES GO HERE */}
```